# How can I select a pixel by its spatial coordinates in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to select a pixel in an image using floating-point numbers as indexes. The Matlab documentation [says that this is possible using "spatial coordinates"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/images/brcu_al-1.html). However, it doesn't provide any clues on how to do it. How can I select a pixel from an image using floating-point indexes ("spatial coordinates")?

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
i = imread('pout.tif')
get_pixel_by_spatial_coords(i, 1.5, 3.63)
```

What's the real name of the function `get_pixel_by_spatial_coords`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the linked article on spatial coordinates was only describing the coordinate systems used by various image plotting routines.

Your your purpose, simply round the number.  Depending on the context, use one of:

```
i(round(1.5), round(3.63))
i(floor(1.5), floor(3.63))
i(ceil(1.5),  ceil(3.63) )
```

Comment: Thanks. You must be right, because I've been unable to find anything about using the spatial coordinate system in your own programs. However, that seems like a pointless thing to include in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html):

> `ginput` raises crosshairs in the current axes to for you to identify points in the figure, positioning the cursor with the mouse. The figure must have focus before `ginput` can receive input. If it has no axes, one is created upon the first click or keypress.

Comment: I don't want to display the image; I just want to read pixels using floating-point coordinates.